# $\frac{n}{2} < 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{2^n -1}$ is not true for every $n > 1, n \in \mathbb{N}$, right?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

So I found an exercise where it is required to prove that for every $n > 1, n \in \mathbb{N}$ the inequality is true:

$$\frac{n}{2} < 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{2^n -1} < n$$

I found that disturbing since I think that for n > 5 that is simply not true (the left hand side is wrong). Can somebody ensure me in my thinking or tell me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Your infinite sum must be wrong as the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n-1}$ converges

Comment: You see $$ \frac{1}{2} \le \sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} \frac{1}{k}  \le 1$$

Comment: @QC_QAOA: Hm, I think you didn't read carefully the sum

Comment: @QC_QAOA I think it should be interpreted as $\sum_{k=1}^{2^n -1}\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: You mean that who is right? Me?

Comment: You are right, it is easy to prove the opposite inequality by induction if the sum is $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^k-1}$, but in that case, the term $\frac{1}{2}$ shouldn't be present. You are not right, if the sum is $\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}\frac{1}{k},$ which is the sum you posted.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. It is therefore important to always look what the exact sum is on the base of an example that is provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This inequality arises from a familiar argument to show that the harmonic series is divergent.

Let $$a_n = \sum_{k = 0}^{2^n - 1} \frac{1}{2^n + k} = \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^n + 1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n+1} - 1}.$$  So for instance, $$a_2 = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7}.$$  Each term in $a_n$ is bounded below by $1/2^{n+1}$, and above by $1/2^n$.  Since $a_n$ contains $2^n$ terms, it follows that $$\frac{1}{2} < a_n \le 1$$ for all $n \ge 0$, with equality on the RHS occurring only for $n = 0$; and $$\frac{n}{2} < \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} a_m < n$$ for $n \ge 1$.  But $$\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} a_m = \sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1} - 1} \frac{1}{k} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n - 1}.$$

In fact, we can prove a much tighter bound with calculus, but this is beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The inequalities are true. For each $i$, $$\frac 1 {2^{k+1}} \leq \frac 1 i \leq \frac 1 {2^k}$$ for some $k$. Summing over $i$ the way it's done [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Comparison_test), you'll get your two inequalities.